# iSeries WRKQRY define results field maximum

Tags: ibm-midrange

When trying insert another defined field in a WRKQRY, a 'No room to insert' message is displayed. The Message id is QRY1098.

In the query, we already have 100 defined fields. This may be the maximum allowed, but I cannot find any documentation relating the maximum allowed number of defined fields to confirm this.

Does anyone know if there is a maximum number for defined fields or if it is possible to add more than 100.

I know we should really revisit what the query is doing, but for now I want to determine if we can add more defined fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instinct about there being a maximum was correct. There is a limit of 100 for the number of result fields that can be defined according to page 84 of [this manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/books/sc415210.pdf)

Comment: @Brian Lee did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did, thanks Mike. Apologies for delay in replying, i am still getting used to stack overflow etiquette.